# clojure repl emacs and slime

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I have slime configured for emacs and I can run many different implementations of common lisp. What about running a language like clojure?

I tested this out by modifying my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/slime/")  ; your SLIME directory                                                                                                                                                              
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
     `((sbcl ("/usr/bin/sbcl"))
       (clojure ("/usr/bin/clojure"))
       (ecl ("/usr/bin/ecl"))
      (clisp ("/usr/bin/clisp" "-q -I"))))
;(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl") ; your Lisp system                                                                                                                                                         
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

It seems to work however there is an exception:

```
(progn (load "/home/d2b2/slime/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/tmp/slime.19396"))
```

Also I get a strange message in the mini-buffer:

`polling "/tmp/slime2.4708" .. ddd (Abort with M-x 'slime-abort-connection'.)` where `ddd` is a timer increasing in seconds.

```
Clojure 1.1.0
user=> java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: progn in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
user=> user=>
```

I decided to run a commonlisp interpreter and compare. This is what I get from the `sbcl` interpeter before I get a prompt:

```
(progn (load "/home/d2b2/slime/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/tmp/slime.19396"))

This is SBCL 1.0.55.0.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
*
; loading #P"/home/d2b2/slime/swank-loader.lisp"
STYLE-WARNING: redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>) in DEFMETHOD
STYLE-WARNING:
   Implicitly creating new generic function STREAM-READ-CHAR-WILL-HANG-P.
WARNING: These Swank interfaces are unimplemented:
 (DISASSEMBLE-FRAME SLDB-BREAK-AT-START SLDB-BREAK-ON-RETURN)
;; Swank started at port: 57199.
57199
* STYLE-WARNING:
   redefining THREAD-FOR-EVALUATION (#<STRUCTURE-CLASS
                                       MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION>
                                     #<SB-MOP:EQL-SPECIALIZER
                                       {1004A8CC43}>) in DEFMETHOD
```

Then the common lisp interpreter appears.

1. How do I setup a clojure repl with slime or how can I fix my small issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [swank-clojure](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure) project for using SLIME with Clojure but it's now deprecated in favor of [nrepl.el](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/nrepl.el). My recommendation would be to check out nrepl.el.

nrepl is the *de facto* repl for Clojure, and with nrepl.el it has similar functionality to SLIME - you run a REPL in Emacs, send code to it from your buffer(s), can jump quickly to definitions, get dynamic code completion, etc. The only place I've found it a bit lacking compared to SLIME is debugging, but swank-clojure didn't support SLIME's debugger anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `clojure-swank` is no longer maintained; the preferred way of interacting with Clojure from Emacs is through [nrepl](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl).

You can check our [installation instructions](http://wiki.unto.net/setting-up-clojure-and-slime) for that approach [here](http://wiki.unto.net/setting-up-clojure-and-slimehttp://wiki.unto.net/setting-up-clojure-and-slime); they look extremely simple (though admittedly, I haven't tried them since I haven't used Clojure in a while).